# Is there a method to print a n-bit (like 256-bit) integer in c without using an external library?

Tags: c, x86-64, bigint

I Have found a way to make a n-bit integer and do arithmetic on the integers, But I don't know how to print those integers, My method to make a n-bit integer is just to make an array of, lets say `char`'s, and make the array (size of array elements) / n elements long. Does anyone know how to print these?

- I had an idea to store the powers of 2 ^ x as strings but I realized that would not work.

Comment: If your representation isn't already in base 10, but you've implemented division and modulus on your integers, you can keep dividing by 10 until it hits 0, storing the modulus(es) along the way, then print them reversed and you'll have your number in base 10.

Comment: Printing as hex would be the easiest way if that's an option.

Comment: Did you implement division ? Then write your own function

Comment: There is no way of using standard library functions.

Comment: Get the source code for a library that does this, read it to see how it works, and do the same in your own code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use standard library functions to convert to string or print in base != 2, 4, 8, 16 (generally 2^n).

If you want to print using those bases you can easily write your own function (example one assuming little endian)

```
void printInteger(const void *buff, size_t size, int base)
{
    const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    const unsigned char *uc = buff + size - 1;
    unsigned nbits;
    unsigned mask;

    switch(base)
    {
        case 2:
            nbits = 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            nbits = 2;
            break;
        case 8:
            nbits = 3;
            break;
        case 16:
            nbits = 4;
            break;
        default: 
            return;
    }
    mask =  (1U << nbits) - 1;
    while(size--)
    {
        for(int nb = CHAR_BIT / nbits - 1; nb >= 0; nb--)
        {
            printf("%c", digits[(*uc >> (nb * nbits)) & mask]);
        }
        uc--;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned test = 0x12345678;

    printInteger(&test, sizeof(test), 16);
    printf("\n");
    printInteger(&test, sizeof(test), 8);
    printf("\n");
    printInteger(&test, sizeof(test), 4);
    printf("\n");
    printInteger(&test, sizeof(test), 2);
    printf("\n");
}
```